# Inverse of a matrix with summation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, summation

Let $ A=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 &1 \\ 
0 & 2 & 1\\ 
 0&  0& 2
\end{pmatrix}$ and $ B=A^{n}+A^{n-1}+...+A+I_{3} $. 
Determine $ B^{-1} $.

So far I found that $ B=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\begin{pmatrix}
2^{k} & k\cdot 2^{k-1} &k\cdot (k+3)\cdot 2^{k-3} \\ 
0 & 2^{k} &k\cdot 2^{k-1} \\ 
0 & 0 & 2^{k}
\end{pmatrix} $.

Comment: Have you seen sequences/series of the form $a^n+a^{n-1}+\cdots+a+1$ before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$B=(A^n-I)(A-I)^{-1}$$

Can you see why $\;A\;$ and $\;A-I\;$ are invertible? Also, can you see why $\;(A-2)^3=0\;$

Comment: I understand that $ B=(A^n-I)(A-I)^{-1} $ and $ detA=\prod_{i=1}^{3}a_{ii} $, but I don't know how to go on with the first relation.

Comment: @ztefelina What "first relation"?

Comment: $ B=(A^{n+1}-I)(A-I)^{-1} $

Comment: @ztefelina That comes from the sum of a geometric series: $$a+ar+ar^2+\ldots+ar^n=a\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}$$ IN our case we're talking of matrices and thus, instead of dividing by $\;A-I\;$ we multiply by its inverse...that's all!

Comment: I know that what you've said is true, but how can I get its inverse from that one?

Comment: @ztefelina What do you want its inverse for??

Comment: That's what I have to find :)

Comment: @ztefelina No, that is *not* what is written in your post....there it is written that you have to find $\;B^{-1}\;$ ...

Comment: For a square matrix A, the inverse is written  $A^{-1}$.

Comment: @ztefelina I know that...so?

Comment: So, when I wrote "Determine $ B^{-1} $ I meant "Determine its inverse" :)

Comment: @ztefelina I know that, too...what is going on? You wrote above that you wanted to know $\;A^{-1}\;$ and I told you that you asked about $\;B^{-1}\;$ ...

Comment: No, I want to know $ B^{-1} $..$ A^{-1} $ is obvious.

Comment: @ztefelina I know...and after my answer also $\;B^{-1}\;$ is obvious. Look at the first line in my answer.

Comment: I do understand it now...sorry for chatting! :)